# Swipe Automation - WebdriverIO - javascript Mobile

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, swipe, mobile-application, webdriver-io

I'm new to javascript and I'm following this code but when starting automation it doesn't slide down page. (mobile)

```
    `$(FORMS_ICON_HOME_SCREEN).click()
    const {height} = driver.getWindowSize()
    const anchorPercentage = 50
    const startPointPercentage = 90
    const endPointPercentage = 10

    const anchor = height * anchorPercentage / 100
    const startPoint = height * startPointPercentage / 100
    const endPoint = height * endPointPercentage / 100

    await $(FORM_HEADER_TEXT).click()
    driver.touchPerform([
        {
            action: 'press',
            options: {
                x: anchor,
                y: startPoint
            }
        },
        {
            action: 'wait',
            options: {
                ms: 1000
            }
        },
        {
            action: 'moveTo',
            options: {
                x: anchor,
                y: endPoint
            }
        },
        {
            action: 'release',
            options: {}
        }
    ])
    await $(ACTIVE_BUTTON).click()
   });
  });
```

`
As I'm starting, putting as much detail as possible, please. Thank u

Comment: Hey! could you add more details like what version of node, webdriverio and appium are you using?

Comment: appium -1.22.2, webdriverIO: "^7.16.16", node: v16.14.0

Comment: Starting from node 16 webdriverio sync mode doesn't work. you have to use async/await to execute the script correctly.